# Question about GCC Optimizer and why this code always returns 42?

Tags: c, gcc, optimization

I ran into an error recently where a variable was initialized inside a switch statement. I started playing around with this more and realize I don't know the first thing about what GCC is trying to do in some of these optimizations.

[Given this code:](https://godbolt.org/z/VE9YaV)

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
       switch (argc) {
               case 1000: return 42;
               int y = 24;
               default: return y;
       }
       return argc;
}
```

The generated code always returns 42. What is going on? Why does the `int y = 24` muck everything up?

```
$ gcc -Wall -Werror -O2 -c test.c
$ objdump -drwCS -Mintel test.o

testo.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

Disassembly of section .text.startup:

0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:   b8 2a 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x2a
   5:   c3                      ret
```

Comment: Returning `y` would be undefined behavior as the initialization of that variable can never be reached, hence the compiler is free to assume that only the `1000` case can ever happen. (From the compilers point of view, things which _would be_ undefined behavior can never happen and it optimizes accordingly)

Comment: I updated my code to include a return statement outside the switch, which still generates the same code. Are you saying that the behavior for the rest of the function is undefined at that point?

Comment: The return outside of the switch doesn't matter, you've got a `default` with a return in the switch. Since this return is undefined behavior, the whole `default` case can never happen, so `argc` __must be__ `1000`. To make this clear, the compiler doesn't _just remove_ undefined paths, it assumes _these paths can never happen when you run the program_, thats why the compiler assumes `argc` can never be anything other than `1000` at runtime.

Comment: That's really interesting. My intuition is that a switch statement with or without a default will still have its cases evaluated and that a behavior would exist if you can't match a case. Since argc is clearly not equal to 1000 all the time.

Comment: But what would it return when `argc` is not 1000? You don't know, the compiler doesn't know. The line `int y = 24;` never executes, so you're returning a uninitialized value, which the compiler doesn't like at all. Since it's uninitialized anyway, it can just return `42` as you're not allowed to assume any particular value to be returned. 42 is just as good as 1, 15 or -3546465. Is uninitialized, undefined.

Comment: Okay, last follow-up. Thanks for helping out. So, is it the line never executing or that it is cross-initialization and ambiguous? Because, for example https://godbolt.org/z/P7_80F y is defined initially here, but then the CI happens.

Comment: @JustinVanHorne: [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633) might be interesting. Optimizing compilers these days are sneaky, even if their intentions to speed up execution are noble.

Comment: Interestingly, GCC reports the jump over initialisation when compiling C++ code, but not for C code.  I don't see why it's less warning-worthy in C, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    switch (argc) {
        case 1000: return 42;
        int y = 24;
        default: return y;
    }
    return argc;
}
```

To explain this a bit more, a switch doesn't exactly do a linear progression. The logic equivalent to this would be:

"If argc is 1000, return 42. Otherwise return y"

The `int y = 24;` is never used since it's never reached, the compiler can optimize this out, and since there's UB in the case of a default, it might as well return 42.

To fix this and behave the way I suspect you intend, you just need to declare `y` outside of the switch statement.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int y = 24;
    switch (argc) {
        case 1000: return 42;
        default: return y;
    }
    return argc;
}
```

Comment: Oh, it was intentional. I was reproducing a bug that was left undiscovered. I understand that it is undefined behavior, but I am just curious about the optimization paths. So, gcc in -O2 is like "I got this. No warnings or errors. I'll just get rid of the code that doesn't make sense." but in -O0 it actually emits a warning about y being potentially uninitialized. For example, here is y being defined (but then a cross-initialization is attempted) https://godbolt.org/z/P7_80F the logic is to still ditch the default because the cross-initialization makes it undefined?

Comment: In any case marking your reply as accepted. It's undefined behavior. Compiler can do what it wants. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug that it does this. Compilers will often make decisions like that when compiling

Comment: Re “The `int y = 24;` is never used”: It is used; it defines `y`. Per C 2018 6.2.4 6, the object `y` is created (its lifetime begins) when execution enters the block of the `switch` statement, but initialization is not performed until execution reaches the declaration (hence, in this case, never). So the definition is used in some way (to define `y`), although its initialization is never executed.

Answer (score 4):

Cases in a `switch` are to be regarded as labels. If we translate your code to the equivalent goto-spaghetti, it might be easier to understand:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
  if(argc == 1000) 
    goto label_1000;
  else 
    goto label_default;

  label_1000: return 42;

  int y = 24;

  label_default: return y;

  return argc;
}
```

The `goto label_default` jumps past the label initialization of `y` and so it doesn't necessarily get executed. The same thing happens in your switch.

Best practice when declaring variables inside switches is therefore to always use a compound statement per case:

```
case 1000:
{
  int y = 24;
  break;
}
```

Apart from preventing spaghetti bugs, this also reduces the scope of the variable to the specific `case`.

Comment: What about in something like https://godbolt.org/z/P7_80F ? Is the compiler just confused about the initialization of y at this point?

Comment: @JustinVanHorne That's essentially the very same kind of spaghetti as my goto example. The outer `y` is never used and the `return y` refers to the inner `y`, which is never initialized.